# How are such non-answers ok? Flag declined!

Tags: discussion

I recently reported [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45938/8527) and to my surprise the moderator saw no problem with this answer.

The reason for declining the flag was that "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

I see several problems with this answer

1. It doesn't actually answer the question and is beyond low quality as it is off-topic. Moderator classed it as 'technically wrong' but this is beyond inaccurate imo.

It is actually just a random statement about something unrelated to the question!

2. It explicitly makes the unsubstantited claim of other answers being incorrect.

> The other answer here, btw., has nothing to do with share of merits, but answers question on giving (of things) toward certain.

3. It doesn't address the tags of the question, even if one spends time looking for the answer in the link.
4. It links to a german site owned by the person who posted the answer. Imho answer appears to be spam-like linking to a website, which is a rather common attribute of the user's posts which are hardly intelligible.
5. I would say that the formatting of the link fails to meet [community guidelines](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1802/does-se-have-a-policy-about-linking-to-ones-own-research-sites-and-blogs)

Excerpt;

> In my experience, posts with links are not downvoted if all these
> conditions are met:
>
> - you paraphrase the content of the linked item (possibly omitting details or examples)
> - you identify the author (yourself, MSDN, etc)
> - **someone could benefit from the answer without reading the linked item at all**
> - you include information to let the reader decide if clicking the link is worthwhile
>
> For example:
>
> > You can use the CircularLabelsStyle
> > custom property for this, for example:
> >
> > ```
> >   chart1.Series["Series1"]["CircularLabelsStyle"] = "Circular";
> > ```
> >
> > I [blogged
> > about this last year](http://example.com), with some sample
> > code.
>
> The other extreme, an answer that says nothing more than "here" or
> "read this" or "please read" and is a link, I will not just downvote
> but flag as not an answer, and I don't care whether it's the
> definitive documentation from the owner of the technology, another
> question on the same SE site, or just a blog you wrote yourself.

I hope these issues are addressed because trying to look for value in such answers & links, trying to have them mended, let alone having to raise the issue on meta is **a huge waste of time** and puts me off from using the service. If this goes then i probably misunderstood what the point of raising a flag is.

You say 'flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer' but 3 top reasons to raise a flag is it being

1. Spam - primarily promoting a service
2. Rude or abusive - such that it is inappropriate for respectful discourse
3. Not an answer - doesn't attempt to answer the question

I think this answer is arguably all three of those.

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding Stack Exchange policies on answer deletion vs. downvotes:

The moderators will definitely delete answers which are:

- Spam (which of course, is unrelated to Buddhism)
- Rude and abusive content - this may include [rude criticism of other Buddhist schools](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/471)
- Not an answer - usually meant as a comment, or a new question, or it is completely unrelated to the question (e.g. question asks about meditation and the answer literally talks about Buddha statues)
- Clearly off-topic - e.g. 100% Christian preaching or 100% Muslim preaching
- Very low quality and unsalvageable - severe formatting or content issues like completely unintelligible posts, rambling, gibberish
- Completely in a non-English language

All non-deleted answers are expected to:

- Not meet the answer deletion criteria mentioned above (i.e. spam, rude and abusive content, not an answer, clearly off-topic, very low quality and unsalvageable)
- Be on-topic i.e. most or all of the answer is related to any mainstream school or tradition of Buddhism (including Theravada, Mahayana, Vajrayana and sub-schools like Zen, Pure Land, Ch'an, Madhyamaka, Yogachara, Sarvastivada, Sautrantika, Kagyu, Nyingma, Dzogchen, Nichiren, Secular Buddhism etc.)

**All on-topic answers which are technically wrong or inaccurate should be downvoted and not deleted.** The Stack Exchange policies are quoted below.

According to [this Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/212749) for the question ["How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/212749)", the criteria for answer deletion is:

> For answers, any post that is [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/148099) (should be a comment,
> doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. Answers that are
> wrong or that dispense poor advice [should be downvoted, not deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264294/1).
>
> These are general guidelines; some communities in the network may
> uphold more specific reasons to delete posts or not. For example, on
> Puzzling.SE, [answers to a puzzle without explanation are subject to
> deletion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1493), and some technical sites will delete answers which are not
> only wrong but also harmful when tried.

So, this means we can add additional criteria for deletion, if we have extremely good reasons.

Also, according to [this Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264294/212749) for the question "[Why shouldn't I delete wrong answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264293/212749)":

> "Wrong" as in "completely unrelated to the question"? Go ahead and
> delete those.
>
> "Wrong" as in "yes, that will solve the problem, but that's a bad
> idea"? Those should be downvoted. Think of it as a lesson - showing a
> bad solution can be helpful as well, especially if it's an obvious
> solution that others may gravitate towards and/or when accompanied by
> an explanation (say, in a comment) of *why* it's a bad solution.
>
> "Wrong" as in "this doesn't solve the issue, but it an obvious attempt
> at providing a solution" is trickier. The appropriate action here
> would depend on what the answer actually was. In most cases, I would
> go with downvoting as well or, frankly, not voting at all.

What is a good answer that should be upvoted?

- Technically on-topic, correct and accurate, with elaboration
- Addresses and answers all parts of the question
- Related to the tags of the question. For e.g. if the question's tags include only `theravada` and `pali-canon`, then the questioner limits the scope to Theravada and Pali Canon only.
- Preferably substantiated using scriptural quotes or commentaries or the opinion of experts, but this is not strictly required as the poster could answer using his or her experience and expertise. Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/138/471) for the Buddhism Meta SE question "[Is “opinion based” a reason for closing a question?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/137/471)"
- Answers to questions requesting for references (and tagged using `reference-request`) should include relevant references

Flags should be used for answers meeting the criteria for deletion above, and not used for answers that should be downvoted.

---

Regarding the user's own websites, the policies are stated in "[Does SE have a policy about linking to one's own research, sites, and blogs?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1802/471)".

---

For [the specific answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45938/8527) in question:

The answer in question was written by Samana Johann, whose command of the English language is very poor. His native language is German. I believe he is a Theravada Buddhist monk based in South East Asia.

Oftentimes, Samana Johann's answers are good or at least meaningful, as also opined by moderator ChrisW in [this comment](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/to-protect-the-integrity-of-buddhism-does-bse-take-any-measures-to-prevent-ai-b#comment6087_2620). Usually, many of his answers go in the direction of "*the other answers explain what you're asking, but you've got your priorities wrong. This is what's better to focus on ...... because ......*"

However, due to his lack of fluency in English and very awkward articulation, what he meant to express in his answers is often unclear and needs to be improved significantly. I myself have edited a number of his answers to make them clearer, if I managed to understand them myself.

So, for the flag, I decided that it looks more like a technically wrong or low quality (but not very low quality) answer than completely off-topic. It looks at least 40 - 50% on-topic, but the articulation in English and grammar has to be improved tremendously. It's not completely gibberish.

In any case, we don't intend to punish users for their poor command of English. We also have other users who write very good answers, but their command of English is poor, because English is not their first language. In this case, we would like other users to improve their answers by editing, but such edits should not change the original intention of the author.

Hence, I decided to give Samana Johann the benefit of the doubt and decided that this answer is meant to be downvoted rather than deleted. Also, it should be edited for improvement, and a disclaimer should be added to state that this is the user's own website. A summary of the website should be added to the answer, although I don't understand what it's about at the moment.

In summary, I feel, "the baby should not be thrown out with the bathwater" for this answer.

Of course, I welcome the other moderators to give a second opinion on this answer.

Comment: If this is ok then i will stop flagging and commenting on other people's answers altogether because it is obviously a waste of time and there is little to no point in doing so because you set the bar for what goes so low. It is fine by me.

Comment: "I decided that it looks more like a technically wrong or low quality " + "and decided that this answer is meant to be downvoted rather than deleted". Did you downvote at least?

Comment: @SlayingDefilements Yes, I did downvote.

Answer (score 0):

**It doesn't actually answer the question**

I think you're right. The questions asks, "What did the Buddha say about this?"

The answer doesn't seem to answer that. Instead it:

- Explains what merit is
- Explains how to share merit
- Explains why to share merit

It does add some information for the avid reader. For example it gives the term *Pattānuppadāna* and given that you can find references of your own, [for example here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/pattidana):

> Though in the older texts very seldom mentioned (e.g. A.VII.50), it
> is, however, a widespread custom in all Buddhist countries. It is
> presumed that moral merit, especially that acquired through giving
> alms, can be transferred to others, apparently for the reason that
> one's own good deeds may become to others, especially to departed
> relatives and friends reborn in the ghost realm, an inducement to a
> happy and morally wholesome state of mind.
>
> Transference of merit is advocated (though without mentioning the term
> patti-dāna) in the Tirokudda Sutta (Khp. and Petavatthu) and its Com.
> (Khp. Tr.).
>
> It is one of the ten 'bases of meritorious action' (puññakiriyavatthu,
> q.v.), called there pattānuppadāna. (App.).
>
> See 'The Doctrine of Reversible Merit by F. L. Woodward. Buddhist
> Review (London), Vol. I (1914), p. 38.

**It explicitly makes the unsubstantiated claim of other answers being incorrect**

That's a reference to [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45942/254) -- it's a reasonable comment, that the quote in that answer is about sharing wealth.

**It doesn't address the tags of the question, even if one spends time looking for the answer in the link.**

The tags are "merit" and "reference-request".

It certainly addresses the topic of "merit", much less so the "reference-request".

As I said previously I think there are some useful references in the linked content, though you have to do a tiny bit of work to make the reference useful.

**Imho answer appears to be spam-like linking to a website**

Most of my answers link to one of a handful of web-sites (ones I'm familiar with), and some of my answers link to other answers on this site. I assume Samana Johann is doing something similar in referencing the sangham.net site.

I don't consider it "spam". [Spamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming) is:

- "Unsolicited messages", usually for commercial reasons (and often via email)
- "Usenet convention defines spamming as excessive multiple posting"

However this post isn't "unsolicited" (because it's posted in answer to a question someone asked), and it's not "excessive multiple posting" (because he hasn't been posting the same answer in reply to multiple questions).

**I would say that the formatting of the link fails to meet community guidelines**

Yes it's a "link-only answer" and is in that way far from ideal.

A fix would be to edit the post, to quote a relevant extract from the linked content -- that might be better than deleting the post, given that the post may be helpful -- I'm reluctant to delete it just because of how it's formatted.

I'm also reluctant to make the edit, partly because it's late on Sunday and I'm posting here on Meta instead, and partly because he has views about copyright and I don't want to trigger more complaints about Stack Exchange using a "CC BY-SA 4.0" license, technically I don't have permission to repost here what he write there -- and though I could argue that my doing that would be "fair use" I don't want to risk an argument.

**Rude or abusive**

No I think he was posting out that the other answer might be taking its quote out of context -- which is fair enough, encouraging the reader to re-read the quoted text with a discerning eye -- I don't think the way he did that was rude or abusive.

> The other answer here, btw., has nothing to do with share of merits, but answers question on giving (of things) toward certain.

I suppose the phrase "nothing to do with" could be milder:

> By the way, the quote in the other answer here wasn't about sharing merits -- it's about making merit by sharing wealth (and with advice about different kinds of making wealth).

But I don't try to read "tone" into Samana Johann's posts, I'm lucky if I can understand it literally.

If you read the examples though of [Unacceptable Behavior](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/conduct#unacceptable-behavior) I don't think he's posting like that.

Comment: "That's a reference to [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/45942/254)" except that it was posted prior to that answer being posted. You are wrong and i am appalled of you thus boldly asserting this, just goes to show that you are an advocate here.

Comment: If you said that the answer pointed out a way for one to benefit from another's merit, practice of mudita, as a close thing to 'sharing merit', that is true. If you said that the website has a few references to the canonical take sharing merit, that i can accept. Still neither the  answer nor the link provides the actual references answering the question and the answer puts down other people's answers.

Comment: Ah you're right, I didn't notice the timestamp. So whether the claim is substantiated depends on how you understand AN 10.177, is that right -- i.e. whether the *dana* which the brahmans are giving consists of "merit" or only "of things"? And it was *your* quote that was being criticised.

Comment: I don't know what his problem with my answer was, the user hardly speaks english and i can't read minds. I did understand that he thought it wasn't relevant.

Comment: "Still neither the answer nor the link provides the actual references answering the question." That's true. I think its format could theoretically be improved by editing but I'm not sure I will this time. Another thing is that I take [this comment](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/moderating-answers-which-dont-answer-the-question#comment3241_1677) to be the community consensus on that topic.

Comment: Who is Crab Bucket? ... which community is in consensus, the 4 people that upvoted the comment 7 years ago? Crab Bucket, you and who else? Because i am not in consensus at all... Anyway, these are rethorical questions. I see no point in discussing this further.

Comment: I will as you as well, why don't you downvote it?

Comment: @SlayingDefilements Samana Johann is saying that your quote is about giving gifts to the dead. It's about charity and not sharing merit. He is making a distinction between the two. The plot twist is that he might be saying that sharing merit in the Canon actually refers to mudita but may have been corrupted or misunderstood later, but I haven't deciphered the answer fully yet. And he is not rude. He is simply pointing out that your answer is about charity rather than sharing merit. Hence his answer is not off-topic and doesn't merit deletion. It may be technically wrong or inaccurate though.

Comment: I think I got it now. Samana Johann is trying to say that telling others about the good things that you have done (i.e. your merits), so that they may practice mudita and brighten their minds, is you sharing your good merits with them. And I think that needs to be backed up by the Canon if possible. On the other hand, your quote is about charity, rather than sharing merits, according to him.

Comment: @ruben2020 I'm not sure it's about charity: I think it it might be about "ritual sacrifice", some brahmanic rites, perhaps funeral rites (which are repeated on anniversaries). I think that brahmins are generally portrayed as have some wrong view in the suttas, perhaps they're advocating some material transaction -- e.g. https://www.worldhistory.org/Brahmanism/ "The Vedas moved the peoples’ relationship with the supernatural from the day-to-day rituals of honoring spirits in a quid pro quo kind of contract to understanding the origin of all existence and the meaning of one’s life".

Comment: In the sutta, the Buddha is portrayed as saying that benefit may accrue to "hungry ghosts" (though not to animals and those in hell). [Piya Tan's essay](https://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/2.6a-Dasaka-Janussoni-S-a10.177-piya.pdf) on 10.177 does describe it as being about "transfer of merit" and relevant to (an explanation of) Buddhist practice; though he also writes, "very little support from the early canon", "the the rise of religious
materialism and laicization of the monastic members during the post-Buddha period in India", and so on.

Comment: @SlayingDefilements "which community is in consensus, the 4 people that upvoted the comment 7 years ago?" A joined the site a little after it was started (by other people). Not very long very after that I was asked to help moderate it (as one of the original moderators wanted to stop). At the time, Meta was more active -- as you might see from some topics having [10 or 20 votes](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes) which they wouldn't these days. Generally people discussed what content should be allowed and how the site should be moderated.

Comment: I think I posted [this question](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1676/254) soon after becoming moderator. There aren't a lot of answer or a lot of upvotes, but that comment seemed to be a consensus among those who voted. I generally tried to ask the community what rules they wanted, instead of imposing my opinion or even Stack Exchange conventions, which is how we ended up with non-standard policies [like this](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254) and [all the site-specific FAQs](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) more generally.

Comment: The participation rate on Meta has declined since then, but I (and I think all moderators do) continue to moderate the site more-or-less "as we have always done". Occasionally one user or another questions some-or-other policy, but I reckon one vote from someone today doesn't override a consensus established by several people originally. Yes some people wish the site were otherwise -- more strict, more expert -- and say that it would be more popular if it were so (but I suppose there's no way of knowing that, and that we can't please everyone).

Comment: Occasionally some minor early policy is overturned, [like this one](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2492/254). My "bright line" as a moderator, the bit of the job that I consider important, is more around posts that seem hostile, towards other users or other schools of Buddhism. And, to "take action" when it appears that *several* users are getting upset by something or someone. I've had long dialogs with Samana Johann in the past; in my opinion his posts are much improved, e.g. trying the answer the OP without writing to complain about the site and its users, and relatively welcome.

Comment: @ChrisW I think I got it completely now. There are 2 ways to share merit according to his answer - inviting others to participate in your charity, like "let's donate together" and telling others about your good deeds so that they can practice mudita and brighten their minds.

Comment: @ruben2020 Something like that. :-) I'm not sure he'd want to call it "his" site but I think it was created (by a lay supporter) for him (and others) to use. Its [introductory page](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php) says it exists for "a community delighted in meritorious deed" -- and so "sharing merit" (and encouraging virtuous behavior) is maybe fundamental to how he views his interactions with lay-people. The [front page of the main site](https://sangham.net/) implies it's meant to be a field of merit and a good inspiration.

Comment: I think SJ is probably correct in that merit can't be shared altogether and that the quote i posted is about gifts.

Comment: Are you planning to moderate the answer @ChrisW?

Comment: @SlayingDefilements No -- I think it's non-hostile (harmless) and tangentially relevant to the topic (beneficial). I don't want to quote from the linked content for fear of offending his sensibilities about copyright; and if there were other content I wanted to add, then I might as well do that a different answer. The only plausible reason for moderating (i.e. deleting) the answer would IMO be because we have a strong policy about the "reference-request" tag -- but I don't want to try to (again) explain the intricacies of site-specific policy to him.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your effort in getting to the bottom of this.

Comment: For the record i do find it very unfortunate that he doesn't follow normal procedures. Eg his remark on the alleged wrongness of my answer should be posted as a comment under my answer, preferably in a comprehensible language and somewhat substantiated. I also think you should downvote the answer as well. Other than this i don't want to participate anymore because it is a huge waste of time. I here request a 1 year ban be placed on the account as a form of self exclusion because i am hestitatant about deleting the account. I will see how the site is doing in 1 year and maybe reconsider.

Comment: I don't like the moderation of this site, it's very tedious and seems political to me. Also what you said about old policies which can no longer be overturned due to lack of participation makes me want to wait and see how that works out.

Comment: Other than that thanks for putting up with me and i hope ya'll do well, soon DD will be back to entertain you as well :-)

Comment: Also want to add that it's not about SJ and the particular issue itt. I am just tired of getting into arguments when i leave comments and wasting time discussing moderation.